# Add capacity to Ford Fulkerson algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, ford-fulkerson

I have a working php implementation of Ford Fulkerson algorithm, based on this great article http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

At the moment, the matrix that control the algorithm can have in its cells a value of 1 or 0, to represent the possibility of every employee to work in that position. I would like to add capacity to the algorithm, basically place in the matrix higher values, like 2, 3 and so on to express the preference to choose an employee instead of another.

Do You have any suggestion on how to edit the algorithm to add capacity?

This is the algorithm code:

```
function maxMatch($matrix, $cols) {
    $match = array();
    foreach ($cols as $v => $item) {
        $match[$item] = -1;
    }
    $result = 0;
    foreach ($matrix as $u => $row) {
        $seen = array();
        foreach ($cols as $v => $item) {
            $seen[$item] = 0;
        }
        if ($this->checkVertex($matrix, $u, $seen, $match)) {
            print_r($match);
            $result++;
        }
    }
    return $match;
}

function checkVertex($matrix, $u, &$seen, &$match) {
    foreach ($matrix[$u] as $v => $row) {
        if ($matrix[$u][$v] && !$seen[$v]) {
            $seen[$v] = TRUE;
            if ($match[$v] < 0 || $this->checkVertex($matrix, $match[$v], $seen, $match)) {
                $match[$v] = $u;
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

This is how I create the matrix:

```
function createMatrix($year, $month, $day, $shift) {
    global $sql;

    $result = $sql->query("VERY HUGE SELECT FOR EMPLOYEES AND POSITIONS MATCH");

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $matrix[$row['employee']][$row['position']] = 1;
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

Thanks a lot, 
Marco

Comment: What's the target goal in your modified problem? It is not clear how you determine solution 1 is better than solution 2?

Comment: now the algorithm place in a position one of the available employees. i would like to create an order of preference for the employees for a position, like placing employees that worked less on that particular position. thanks

Comment: So, you are looking for [weighted bipartite matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs)?

Comment: yes i thought the same. I tried to edit the algorithm to count the weight, but I had no luck finding a working solution

Comment: You are going to need a different approach for this, and not try to modify the unweighted version. [The hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) solves this problem quite efficiently.

Comment: thanks a lot! i will try to use that approach